# Automatically duplicate the same formula when adding new rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, spreadsheet

Let's say we have a formula in column B, for example `=LEFT(A2; FIND(" "; A2))` but it could be anything else.

[image]

**How to make that, when adding a new row in the future (here on row #4), the formula of column B is automatically duplicated/populated?** (without having to manually do a copy paste of C3 into C4)

Comment: If you format those cells (A1 through B3) as a table, then new rows should automatically have the formula applied.

Comment: @PrestonManess How do you format them as a table? I think this might be the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting the cells as a table should automatically make the formula apply to subsequent rows.

1. Select the cells, including headers
2. Go to the Home tab of the ribbon
3. Select Format as Table
4. Pick desired style
5. Tick the "my data has headers" checkbox
6. Click Ok
7. Observe new rows having the formula automatically.

You can also view a sample video here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhsnh0sstjt3txj/EXCEL_4f5NGRxOXg.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Thanks! Here when I insert text in cell `A5`, nothing happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4L4Y.png

Comment: Is there a specific way to add a new row at the end of the table @PrestonManess? If it takes more than one click / one keyboard shortcut, then just doing CTRL+C CTRL+V might be easier. Looking for the easiest solution :)

Comment: After entering text into the cell, if you hit TAB (or ENTER in this case since there are only two columns and the last one is a formula), then the formula should automatically evaluate.

Comment: It works with Excel 2016, thanks @PrestonManess! (note: it doesn't with Excel 2007)